# Question about transient analysis in LTspice

Tags: transformer, ltspice, transient, analysis

[image: Transient Analysis]

Can anyone explain the function of these three options in transient analysis?

1. Stop simulating if steady state is detected
2. Step the load current source
3. Skip initial operating point solution

I was getting the error message "Dont know how to detect this circuit's steady state." when starting the simulation with option 1 and 2. What type of circuit can use these analysis options?

Comment: Both your questions are answered in the LTspice help (press F1 to open it) under `Transient Analysis Options`.  Click on each option for more info.  Also web-archived here:  https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_TRAN_Modifiers.htm